# Unsplit reduced data table based on two factors in R

Tags: r, split, dataframe, lapply, split-apply-combine

Suppose I have a data frame in R where I would like to use 2 columns "factor1" and "factor2" as factors and I need to calculate mean value for all other columns per each pair of the above mentioned factors. After running the code below, the last line gives the following warnings:

```
Warning messages:
1: In split.default(seq_along(x), f, drop = drop, ...) :
  data length is not a multiple of split variable
```

...

Why is it happening and what should I do to make it right?
Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
# Create data frame
myDataFrame <- data.frame(factor1=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), factor2=c(3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5), val1=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), val2=c(9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1))  

# Split by 2 columns (factors)
splitDataFrame <- split(myDataFrame, list(myDataFrame$factor1, mydataFrame$factor2))

# Calculate mean value for each column per each pair of factors
splitMeanValues <- lapply(splitDataFrame, function(x) apply(x, 2, mean))

# Combine back to reduced table whereas there is only one value (mean) per each pair of factors
MeanValues <- unsplit(splitMeanValues, list(unique(myDataFrame$factor1), unique(mydataFrame$factor2)))
```

EDIT1: Added data frame creation (see above)

Comment: Please provide some sample data so that we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Richard Scriven: Thanks, just added the line that creates data frame, see above in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to calculate the mean for all other columns than the factors, you can use the formula syntax of `aggregate()`

```
aggregate(.~factor1+factor2, myDataFrame, FUN=mean)
```

That returns

```
  factor1 factor2 val1 val2
1       1       3    2    8
2       2       4    5    5
3       3       5    8    2
```

Your `split()` method didn't work because when you `unsplit` you must have the same number of rows as when you split your data. You were reduing the number of rows for all groups to just one row. Plus, `unsplit` really should be used with the exact same list of factors that was used to do the `split` otherwise groups may get out of order. You could to a `split` and then `lapply` some collapsing function and then `rbind` the list back into a single data.frame if you really wanted, but for a simple mean, `aggregate` is probably best.

Comment: Thanks, your method worked! One question though, when I tried unsplit, I used unique function in the list, so the factor vectors should have also been reduced. Why did not that work?

Comment: The main problem is that your splitMeanValues is not a list of data.frames, it is a list of named vectors. The `apply` function does not play well with data.frames, it converts the input to a matrix, and ultimately to a vector thanks to your reduction function.

Answer (score 1):

The same result can be obtained with `summaryBy()` in the `doBy` package. Although it's pretty much the same as `aggregate()` in this case.

```
> library(doBy)
> summaryBy( . ~ factor1+factor2, data = myDataFrame)
#   factor1 factor2 val1.mean val2.mean
# 1       1       3         2         8
# 2       2       4         5         5
# 3       3       5         8         2
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `aggregate`?

`aggregate(myDataFrame$valueColum, myDataFrame$factor1, FUN=mean)`
`aggregate(myDataFrame$valueColum, myDataFrame$factor2, FUN=mean)`

Comment: Tried: MeanValues <- aggregate(myDataFrame, by=list(myDataFrame$factor1, mydataFrame$factor2), FUN=mean), got error:  arguments must have same length. Still error.